# Retrieve the Value of Dynamicaly Generated Columns from Hbase

Tags: java, database, hbase, dynamically-generated, bigdata

For example, here is some records in a hbase table:

```
123,  column=cf:dcol#0,  value=aaaa
123,  column=cf:dcol#1,  value=bbbb
123,  column=cf:dcol#2,  value=cccc
123,  column=cf:someOtherCol, value=dddd
```

The column dcol# is create dynamically by increasing the last digit.

Is there a way to get all the dcol# columns using native hbase lib without getting all the columns and knowing the number of dcol columns is available for this rowkey.

Thanks in advance for any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve it you can use [ColumnPrefixFilter](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/ColumnPrefixFilter.html). See example below

```
Get get = new Get(Bytes.toBytes(123));
get.addFamily(Bytes.toBytes("cf"));
get.setFilter(new ColumnPrefixFilter(Bytes.toBytes("dcol#")));
Result result = hTable.get(get);
.....
```